# SpringBoot application stuck at springboot logo

Tags: spring-boot, jersey

I have spring boot application integrated with jersey framework.
Now when I try to run that application it just stucks at Spring boot logo and nothing happens after that.

I tried adding -X also , but no logs appear after logo.I tried many changes to my pom but with same result. I cannt proceed further as I am not able to figure out error information.

Any guess how can I debug this issue, I cannot share my code right now.

[Update]
I somehow managed to run the applicaton.Now it goes beyond Sprint Logo

I can see application is started but I am not able to see tomcat starting logs and it just hangs there..

Is it could be issue with using tomcat with springboot and jersy

Comment: What type of logging do you use?!.. do you have a log4j file in you application ?!..

Comment: yes I am using log4j ,private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JerseyApplication.class);

Comment: Can you post your `Logging preferences` from `application.properties`??

Comment: <included>
 <logger name="abc.poc" level="DEBUG" />
</included>

Comment: post your entire log4j file make the root logger to debug

Comment: please post your springboot starting logs

Comment: @Alien01 Were you able to resolve this? I'm facing a similar issue now.

Comment: @anand, how you are starting the application?

Comment: I had this issue because I wasn't setting the spring boot profile.

Answer (score 17):

I was also facing this:

Resolved it by adding "console" config in log4j2.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Configuration status="info" packages="com.citi.area51">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS} [%t] %-5level 
%logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Mine was a port already in use..but the key is to get logging wired to see the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Had some trouble finding the file which was under `src\main\resources`  for me.

Answer (score 6):

The same issue happened to me after I added the following `logback.xml` configuration, because I wanted to limit the noise produced by apache http client:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <logger name="org.apache" level="ERROR" />
  <logger name="httpclient" level="ERROR" />
</configuration>
```

When I added appender and root logger, my app started working again.

```xml
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
```

So, **if you are facing this issue, check configuration of your loggers.**

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me everytime I forget to configure a profile for the current execution, as Spring expects you to explicitly provide it.

Specifically: when executing in local Spring boot expects you to provide the following environment variable:

```
spring.profiles.active=local
```

You can provide it as well as a default execution profile by adding the following snippet in your **application.yml**:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: local
```

Otherwise you would have to configure your own profiles in the code and still explicitly request them when executing your app in the same way as above described for the **local** profile

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question but I faced this issue now. For me the logging configurations were correct, but I forgot to activate any Spring profile (and the logging config was tied to certain profiles).

I had to activate the correct profiles with `-Dspring.profiles.active` VM argument (`SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable should also work).

So if your logging config is based on Spring profiles check your active profiles!