# My Spring boot application Pod is stuck in kubernetes and not being up

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, deployment, profiling, kubernetes-pod

Spring boot application pod is not getting up, neither is failing , it is just stuck. Not getting any clue what is going wrong .Attached screenshot is for logs it is generating
[pod log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FTy7.png)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <deployement-name>
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: <app-name>
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: <app-name>
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/port: "8090"
        prometheus.io/path: "/app/actuator/prometheus"
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsGroup: 3000
        runAsUser: 3000
      containers:
      - name: <app-name>
        image: <url>/REPLACE_ME
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: DB_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: <random>-db-secret
              key: db-user
        - name: DB_PASS
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: <random>-db-secret
              key: db-pass
        - name: spring-profile
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: spring-profile-stage
              key: ENV
        - name: securityaudit.hostname
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: securityaudit-config
              key: securityaudit.hostname
        - name: securityaudit.ipaddress
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: securityaudit-config
              key: securityaudit.ipaddress
        - name: securityaudit.product
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: securityaudit-config
              key: securityaudit.product
        - name: splunkurl
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: splunk-config
              key: splunkurl
        - name: splunktoken
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: hec-token-secret
              key: hec-token
        - name: splunkindex
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: splunk-config
              key: splunkindex
        - name: splunkCertValidDisable
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: splunk-config
              key: splunkDisableCertValidation
        - name: MY_POD_ID
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 4Gi
            cpu: 1
          requests:
            memory: 4Gi
            cpu: 1
        securityContext:
          privileged: false
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8090
        livenessProbe:
           httpGet:
             path: /<app-name>/actuator/health/liveness
             port: 8090
           initialDelaySeconds: 180
        readinessProbe:
           httpGet:
             path: /<app-name>/actuator/health/readiness
             port: 8090
           initialDelaySeconds: 180
           periodSeconds: 10
        volumeMounts:
        - name: <app-name>-heapdump
          mountPath: /<app-name>heapdump
      volumes:
      - name: <app-name>-heapdump
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: <app-name>heap-dump-stage
```

Comment: Are you sure you're writing your logs to stdout?

Comment: i guess, corresponding log4j file is not getting picked in the first place itself , so no further log is being printed

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762547/springboot-application-stuck-at-springboot-logo

Comment: @RakeshGupta i have replaced some part because of security reason

Comment: @RakeshGupta, this link helped. Loggers were missing in my log4j2 file. Thank you so much. You saved my day. A lot to learn!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by @Rakesh Gupta resolved my problem. Pod was up, problem was logging level was not set and i thought something was wrong with the pod itself. Being new to this project , i missed the point to check the logging level
Does this answer your question - stackoverflow.com/questions/40762547/… –